# Как изменить кодировку тела письма загруженного через procmail?

Tags: linux, bash, email, кодировка

Для получения тела письма я использую `fetchmail`, `procmail`, `formail`, и `uudeview`.

Содержимое **.procmailrc**:

```
:0
*^content-Type:
{
   TICKETNAME=$HOME/my/abc_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N`.txt
   FROM=`formail -X From:`        
   BODY=`formail -I ""`
   :0wf
   * ^(To||Cc||BCc).*myemail@email.com
   * ^(From).*somesite.net    
   | echo "$FROM" >> $TICKETNAME; \
     echo "$BODY" >> $TICKETNAME;     
}
```

В результате получаю подобный текстовый файл:

```
From: "ABC DEF"  <abc123@some.net>
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```

Т.е. кодировка первой строки(from) в порядке, а вот тело нечитаемо из-за кодировки(mime).

Как получить весь текстовый файл("from" и "body") в привычной кодировке(unicode)?

Есть у меня, например, `uudeview` - могу ли я его как-то использовать?